# how can be remove all white spaces fron begin of line using tr in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, tr

i know the **sed** syntax for removing whitespaces from begin of line, can it be done using **tr command** ?

my file is file.txt like .

```
    th ht djs
        ncdbh jdhbc ncbs 
     hi nc hdn 
 mued ndc
```

after removing all whitespaces from begin we get file like

```
th ht djs
ncdbh jdhbc ncbs 
hi nc hdn 
mued ndc
```

Comment: what's wrong with sed or other bash tools?

Comment: nothing wrong with sed or other bash tools. i just want to know can it be possible with tr or not . @AvinashRaj

Comment: i dont know how people judge questions . what is wrong asking about this type of questions if i dont know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer to your quesition is **no**. `tr` doesn't support deletion of specific patterns using regex.
The purpose of `tr` is different - [man tr](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/tr.shtml)

If you want to use `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's/^[ \t]*//' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//' input.lst > output.lst
```

with `tr`

```
tr -d ' \t\n\r\f' <input.lst >output.lst
```

Comment: i can do it with sed command my question is- can it be done using tr ?

Comment: @SAC change your tag to tr only.

Comment: no tr -s ' ' will not remove spaces from beginning  of line.

Comment: tr -d '[:blank:]' remove all the spaces not only  begin of line spaces   @Skynet

Comment: Answer had been edited and changed @SAC, try with this one and I'm sure it will work cause I already tried it.

Answer (score 2):

```
while read line; do echo "${line}"; done < File
```

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ while read line; do echo "${line}"; done < File
th ht djs
ncdbh jdhbc ncbs
hi nc hdn
mued ndc
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question text asks about `tr`, but the title is more accommodating, and just asks about doing it without `sed`.

It's impossible with `tr`, because it just considers characters one by one, without regard for context.

For a non-`sed` answer, you might try

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' inputfile
```